# End of Chapter Trope in Megillah

Tags: halacha, minhag, trop-cantillation, 5-megilloth

It is a common custom of many *baalei keriah* (public readers of scripture) to do a special Trope for the end of every chapter in a Megillah (listen e.g. [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Il1EmK887ac&t=542s) at ~13 minutes).  Given that, historically, it was the Christians who originally divided the chapters in the Bible, is this a custom that must/should be continued based on the principle of *minhag yisrael torah hu* or would this qualify as a *minhag taut* (errant custom) that should preferably be abolished?

Comment: @user17001, [Welcome to Mi Yodeya](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks very much for your question! Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting.

Comment: @user17001, DoubleAA noticed that your question had been asked before.  You are welcome to go to that link and check out the answers.

Comment: I mean, how would you feel about someone reading [פעמון זהב ורמון פעמון זהב ורמון](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0228.htm#34) to the tune of "Jingle Bells"? They'd be thrown out of town! ובערת הרע מקרבך‎ Don't let anyone read in your Shul if they bring Christianity into our holy Scripture by doing this.